# Object Oriented Javascript Chapter 4 Exercise 4

Tags: javascript

Hi all I'm learning Javascript with the Stoyan Stefanov's book. I'm stuck on Chapter 4 Exercise 4:

> Imagine the String()constructor didn't exist. Create a constructor
>   function  MyString()that acts like String()as closely as possible.
>   You're not  allowed to use any built-in string methods or properties,
>   and remember that  String()doesn't exist. You can use this code to
>   test your constructor:

```
>>> var s = new MyString('hello');
>>> s[0];
"h"
```

I can't think on a way to achieve "s[0]", at least not with the knowledge I have now.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't a string an array of characters? May be obvious but use that as your starting point. Have you covered arrays yet?

Comment: You're right. But most people who learn a language these days don't know that (or that a char of a charset is just a symbol referenced by a sequence of bits). This isn't me being an old-timer (I'm not)... But especially if JS/C#/AS3/Ruby/Python is your first language, you have no reason to think about it. Even languages without String, but with Char, operator overloads and StdLib(or similar), you don't *have* to know it to start anymore.

Comment: Thanks. Got a down vote for my trouble and the answer accepted broke the terms of the question.  CharAt is a String method. Oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects can have properties of themselves defined using array like syntax. String chars can be accessed with array like syntax.

```
    function MyString (str) { 

this.length = 0; // string length

var i = 0;
while(str[i] != undefined) {
    this.length++;
    i++;
}

for (var i=0; i< this.length;i++)
    {
    this[i]=str[i];
    }
}
var s=new MyString('hello');
alert(s[0]); //h
```

Comment: Thanks! The  "this[i] =" was whats I was missing. Thanks so much

Comment: Word. NP. PS, this is an excellent free ebook on javascript. http://www.syncfusion.com/resources/techportal/ebooks/javascript They make you give them ur email to download, but its totally worth it.

Comment: The question (in the book) clearly states you are NOT allowed to use any string methods therefore this is not a solution.

Comment: @alib_15 you are right. not sure how i missed that. Does this new answer work? Not sure if array access of a string is a cop out or not

Comment: Yes, I think you're on the right lines. Can you make your strings immutable?

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution for this exercice :

```
function MyString(msg){

var array_msg = msg.split("");

array_msg.toString = function(){
    return array_msg.join("");
};

array_msg.valueOf = function(){
    return array_msg.toString();
};

array_msg.charAt = function(i){
    if(array_msg[i] === undefined){
        return array_msg[0];
    }else{return array_msg[i];}
};

array_msg.concat = function(msg2){
    return array_msg.join("")+" "+msg2;
};

array_msg.slice = function(d,f){
    var res = "";
    if(f<0){
        f = array_msg.length + f;
    }
    for(var i=d; i<f; i++){
        res += array_msg[i]
    }
    return res;
};

array_msg.split = function(el){
    return array_msg.toString().split(el);
};

return array_msg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation of the above...more of a tweak than anything

```
var MyString = function (s) {
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
        this[i] = s[i]
    }
    this.length = function() .....
```

You also don't need to assign it to anything as extra as the comment suggests. this[i] will be created for the length of the string passed to s

EDIT:

Part of the question in the book says not to use existing string methods so can't use charAt so I've switched it to s[I]

Answer (score 0):

This is another variation of one of the above solutions but instead of using a for loop I am using a while loop. I don't usually use while loops for these kinds of things but it worked really well here.

Adding the length property is optional.

```
function MyString(str) {
    this.length = 0;    // Creating an optional length property
    this.value = str;
    var i = 0;
    while(str[i] != undefined) {
        this[i] = str[i];
        this.length++;
        i++;
    }
}

var name = new MyString('billy');
console.log(name.value);     // 'billy'
console.log(name[0]);        // 'b'
console.log(name.length);    // 5
```